# Targeting ID of an element isn't working.

Tags: html, url, permalinks

I'm having problem on the page I'm working with, I'm trying to set a permalink with an id so that if the page is fully loaded, it would show the page and it focuses on the element with the ID as its top of the page. But the scenario here, after the focus goes to the ID, eventually the view goes to the top of the page.

The page view should go to the heading that says "Care facilities with rest home and hospital level care"

http://metlifecare.staging.wpengine.com/living-at-metlifecare/assisted-living#care-facility

What could a quick fix. Not familiar with the issue. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a name attribute for the a tag? <a name="care-facility">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Evan Knowles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137269/evan-knowles) said you need to add names to your anchors for the browser to be able to browse there.

Replace

`<a id="trigger-sa" href="http://metlifecare.staging.wpengine.com/living-at-   metlifecare/metlifecare.staging.wpengine.com/living-at-metlifecare/assisted-living#care-facility"></a>`

with

`<a id="trigger-sa" name="care-facility" href="http://metlifecare.staging.wpengine.com/living-at-metlifecare/metlifecare.staging.wpengine.com/living-at-metlifecare/assisted-living#care-facility"></a>`

I see what you are referring to as the 'jump to the top'. It looks like this piece of code make the entire page block and then jumps to the top

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Removing that code stop the jump and makes the #care-facility work correctly.

I have never worked with html2canvas, so I can't comment on what it is doing.

Comment: Your answer saved my whole day. I've been  troubleshooting for hours.

You gave me the hint with that html2canvas. We've been using html2canvas to make exact replica of the current page as printable media. You can try it by clicking the "Print this page", the one with a print icon at the bottom of the content.

What I did to solve the issue was to wrap the html2canvas() function by:
$('.printpage').click(function(){});

Whew! Thanks a lot!

Just curious how did you knew that html2canvas was blocking the entire page?

Comment: I saved your page locally and found that my browser locked (loading spinner stopped) up for a second and then jumped to the top of the page. This made me look into the JS that was being executed and found html2canvas was blocking. After I commented that piece, the blocking was gone and the page jump as well.

Comment: Noted. Thanks again Donovan.